# How many binary words of length n are there in which 0 and 1 occur the same number of times and in which no two 0's are adjacent?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I understand that, in order to satisfy the first two conditions (length n, same number of 0's and 1's) all that needs to be done is

$$ \frac {n!} { \frac {n} {2}! \times \frac {n} {2}!} $$

but I'm not sure how to account for the third condition (no consecutive 0's).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not many. If you have too many consecutive 1s, there will be more 1s than 0s in the word. So we can count them:

- If the word starts with a 1, the only option is 1010...1010.
- If the word starts with a 0 and ends with a 1, the only option is 0101...0101.
- If the word starts and ends with a 0, we need to have one pair of 1s inside. These can start on all even positions except the last one (e.g. 011010, 010110), which is on $n/2-1$ positions.

So the final solution is $n/2+1$ (for even $n$; for odd $n$ the answer is of course 0).

Comment: Wait, but if n is odd, this will produce a decimal answer.  Do you mean n!/2?

Comment: If $n$ is odd, the word can't have the same number of 0s and 1s.

Comment: Good point.  Thank you for the help!